# Should I stop visiting my relative's house because they drink alcohol there when I'm not present?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol, family

I read in Quran that we shouldn't go to a house where the people living there drink alcohol. However, I have close relatives who do so. They do drinks occasionally, or in any get together and also take shisha, weed, etc. When I'm present, they don't drink alcohol, etc. Even I suggested them not to do this, but they argued with me, and tried to justify that it is halal.  However, Allah never told us that drinking is haram. So later I found it in Quran that we shouldn't visit a house where people drink.

In this circumstances, what should I do? Should I stop visiting some of my relatives' houses?

Comment: Quran prohibits drinking alcohol but where it is saying don't visit house where people drink. Can you provide Sura/verse number ?

Comment: Hello brother, 
I don't remember right now from where, but InShaAllah next time when I'll find it I do want to share it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is already given in here:

> And it has already come down to you in the Book that when you hear the verses of Allah [recited], they are denied [by them] and ridiculed; so do not sit with them until they enter into another conversation. Indeed, you would then be like them. Indeed Allah will gather the hypocrites and disbelievers in Hell all together. ([Surat An-Nisā' 4/140](http://quran.com/4/140))

and here:

> And when you see those who engage in [offensive] discourse concerning Our verses, then turn away from them until they enter into another conversion. And if Satan should cause you to forget, then do not remain after the reminder with the wrongdoing people. ([Surat Al-'An`ām 6/68](http://quran.com/6/68)).

But also drinking alcohol is haram with no doubt.

> O you who have believed, indeed, intoxicants, gambling, [sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah ], and divining arrows are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful. ([Surat Al-Mā'idah 5/90](http://quran.com/5/90))

The verse clearly orders to avoid from intoxicants. Alcohol, weed etc clearly are intoxicants. So, it is forbidden, so it is haram.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother.. its correctly informative.. And yes I should consider to visit their home from now. May Allah bless us all..

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes:

I want to ask you what is 'taqwa'?

Taqwa is to stay away from haram and leave those thing that Allah dislike. We should not go to a place where something is happening that Allah dislike. These type of 'mahfil'(gathering ) are haram in Islam.

**I heard this before but this explain taqwa:**

> Once upon a time Hazrat Umar Farooq asked from Hazrat Abi (RA) Bin Kab about pity.
>    Hazrat Abi Bib Kab said! Have you ever passed from path with full of bushes?
>  Hazrat Umar Farooq said “Yes” when I was grazed the camels of my father I came across many times from those types of paths.
>  Hazrat Kaab (RA) said then how did you pass from these paths?
>  Hazrat Umar(RA) said that I folded my clothes and in this way I avoid myself from the bushes. Then I took every step with full of care.
>  Harat kaab said “It is pity (taqwa)”. Quran e Haqeem said that the purpose of all the actions and worship is Taqwa because when pity is created in the heart of the man then he feels easy to avoid every evil and to make secure himself.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, this is helpful, and I also think so...and somewhere i also read that we should leave the company while they are doing anything wrong but can join again them when they are doing anything that is acceptable..

Comment: @NadiaAli I think you are referring to this verse http://quran.com/4/140 or http://quran.com/6/68

Comment: @Ziyad, Yes exactly mostly the forst one and the second one too. I do remember things that somewhere i read but yet dont have much knowledge to remember the exact verses or the location in Quran. So, thanks a lot for sharing brother..